# Cannot make url point to newly renamed directory in Tomcat

Tags: windows, jsp, url, tomcat, intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ I created directory called `JSP` and I ran it in browser using Tomcat.

It was all good until I decided to rename the directory to `jsp`.

Now, the url only recognizes `/JSP/index.jsp`

How can I make it to actually go to `/jsp/index.jsp`

I am not sure what happened, since JSP folder desn't exist any more ...

Comment: @SanKrish I tried all the below suggestions before I posted the comment, vut it still acts as if it is JSP folder :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sometimes happens with the build not being done completely , Try a `clean and build` .

Also `re-deploy` the app in the server. if the samething persists refresh the project